# Iterate over a ruby list in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a good practice to make this.

In the index page of app, I send a list of messages that should be displayed to user:

```
def index
  @alerts = Alert.all
end
```

In html side, I need to display this as a serie of  [gritter](https://github.com/jboesch/Gritter) messages. So I tried this:

```
  <% @alerts.each do |item| %>
      var message = "<%= escape_javascript(item.message) %>" +
              '<br><br>' +
              '<a href="/alerts/resolve/<%= item.id %>" class="btn-resposta btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" data-remote="true">Resolve this</a>';
      gritter(message);
  <% end %>
```

Is this the right approach ?

Comment: much better if you return a json response intead

Comment: You are right. I got this to work using a div with data-temp attribute. Thanks.

Comment: Would be good to post your own answer so other people can benefit from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following PericlesTheo suggestion, I get this to work using a html element to store the list in json format:

### Controller:

```
@alerts = Alert.all
```

### View:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "temp-information", data: {alerts: @alerts.to_json} do %>
<% end %>
```

### Javascript:

```
var alerts = $('.temp-information').data('alerts');
$(alerts).each(function(index, item){
    gritter(item.message);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You are in the right way, but take care about how you generate html code (javascript in your case). It's a good idea to look how the page code was generated.

In your case you are repeating the declaration of "var message" variable as many times as are your messages. So, I recomend something like this:

```
  <% @alerts.each do |item| %>        
      gritter("<%= escape_javascript(item.message) %>" +
              '<br><br>' +
              '<a href="/alerts/resolve/<%= item.id %>" class="btn-resposta btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" data-remote="true">Resolve this</a>');
  <% end %>
```

### Update

You can create a ruby method to escape all javascript you need:

```
def gritter_alerts(alerts)
    code = ""
    alerts.each do |item|
      code += escape_javascript(item.message) +
      '<br><br>' +
      '<a href="/alerts/resolve/<%= item.id %>" class="btn-resposta btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" data-remote="true">Resolve this</a>'+
      "\n";
    end
    code
end
```

And use simply like this:

```
<%= gritter_alerts(@alerts) %>
```